# How to read the TypedArray data in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android and still following some tutorials. One tut is about TypedArray for storing the image information.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.materialme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TypedArray sportsImageResources = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sports_images);
        Log.d(TAG, "sportImageResources: " + sportsImageResources);
        sportsImageResources.recycle();

    }

}
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <array name="sports_images">
        <item>@drawable/img_baseball</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_badminton</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_basketball</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_bowling</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_cycling</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_golf</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_running</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_soccer</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_swimming</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_tabletennis</item>
        <item>@drawable/img_tennis</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

When I see in logcat, the values of TypedArray sportsImageResources are

`[3, 179, 6, 2131165272, 0, 0, 3, 178, 6, 2131165271, 0, 0, 3, 180, 6, 2131165273, 0, 0, 3, 181, 6, 2131165274, 0, 0, 3, 182, 6, 2131165275, 0, 0, 3, 183, 6, 2131165276, 0, 0, 3, 184, 6, 2131165277, 0, 0, 3, 185, 6, 2131165278, 0, 0, 3, 186, 6, 2131165279, 0, 0, 3, 187, 6, 2131165280, 0, 0, 3, 188, 6, 2131165281, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 17, 512, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 16, 250, 1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 16, 400, 1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2131558747, 6, 2131558747, 1073742848, 0, 1, 2131558746, 6, 2131558746, 1073742848, 0, 28, -1, 1, 17170443, 1073742848, 0, 3, 193, 6, 2131165294, 1073742848, 0, 3, 27, 6, 0, 1073742848, 0, 18, -1, 6, 0, 1073742848, 0, 18, 0, 6, 0, 1073742848, 0, 18, 0, 6, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1073742848, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 6, 0, 1073742848, 0]`

How to read this data?

Answer (score 1):

May be this example will help you.

`TypedArray sportsimgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);`

// get resource ID by index
sportsimgs .getResourceId(i, -1)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(sportsimgs .getResourceId(i, -1));

// recycle the array
sportsimgs .recycle();

Comment: I knew about getResourceId(). I'm just wondering why the TypedArray array holds so many values only for a few images.